# Refresh ComboBox while exchanging data to database

Tags: java, database, swing, refresh, jcombobox

I have a program that contains `JComboBox` that getting data from MySQL server database.

When I add data to database the combo Box doesn't show it. 
I must to reopen my program to add the new data to ComboBox.

How can I refresh ComboBox to add new data automatically?

Comment: Who and when adds the data? If it's you ( your app) you can reload the combo at that time.

Comment: Any code to help us to get your problem ? As it is, pretty hard to guess...

Comment: adding data to the database in another app and i want to show that data in this ComboBox in diffrent app without re opening

Answer (score 0):

> How can I refresh ComboBox to add new data automatically?

That is the key. You want to "refresh" the combo box, not create a new combo box.

```
//jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
```

That code creates a new combo box, but you never add the combo box to the frame.

Get rid of that statement. All you need is:

```
jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(list1.toArray()));
```

and the combo box currently visible of the frame will be "refreshed" with new data.